# Is there a Python API for submitting batch get requests to AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The package `boto3` - Amazon's official AWS API wrapper for python - has great support for uploading items to DynamoDB in bulk.  It looks like this:

```
db = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name = "my_region").Table("my_table")

with db.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in my_items:
        batch.put_item(Item = item)
```

Here `my_items` is a list of Python dictionaries each of which must have the table's primary key(s).  The situation isn't perfect - for instance, there is no safety mechanism to prevent you from exceeding your throughput limits - but it's still pretty good.

However, there does not appear to be any counterpart for reading from the database.  The closest I can find is `DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item()`, but here the API is extremely complicated.  Here's what requesting two items looks like:

```
db_client = boto3.client("dynamodb", "my_region")

db_client.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems = {
        "my_table": {
            "Keys": [
                {"my_primary_key": {"S": "my_key1"}},
                {"my_primary_key": {"S": "my_key2"}}
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

This might be tolerable, but the response has the same problem: all values are dictionaries whose keys are data types (`"S"` for string, `"N"` for number, `"M"` for mapping, etc.) and it is more than a little annoying to have to parse everything.  So my questions are:

> Is there any native `boto3` support for batch reading from DynamoDb, similar to the `batch_writer` function above?

Failing that,

> Does `boto3` provide any built-in way to automatically deserialize the responses to the `DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item()` function?

I'll also add that the function `boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table().get_item()` has what I would consider to be the "correct" API, in that no type-parsing is necessary for inputs or outputs.  So it seems that this is some sort of oversight by the developers, and I suppose I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So thankfully there is something that you might find useful - much like the `json` module which has `json.dumps` and `json.loads`, boto3 has a types module that includes a serializer and deserializer. See [TypeSerializer/TypeDeserializer](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html). If you look at the source code, the serialization/deserialization is recursive and should be perfect for your use case.

Note: Its recommended that you use `Binary`/`Decimal` instead of just using a regular old python float/int for round trip conversions.

```
serializer = TypeSerializer()
serializer.serialize('awesome') # returns {'S' : 'awesome' }

deser = TypeDeserializer()
deser.deserialize({'S' : 'awesome'}) # returns u'awesome'
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: this looks good! I think this will take away most pain points. thank you

Answer (score 8):

There's  the service resource level [batch_get_item](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.ServiceResource.batch_get_item). Maybe you could do something like that :

```
def batch_query_wrapper(table, key, values):

    results = []

    response = dynamo.batch_get_item(RequestItems={table: {'Keys': [{key: val} for val in values]}})
    results.extend(response['Responses'][table])

    while response['UnprocessedKeys']:

        # Implement some kind of exponential back off here
        response = dynamo.batch_get_item(RequestItems={table: {'Keys': [{key: val} for val in values]}})
        results.extend(response['Response'][table])

    return results
```

It will return your result as python objects.

Comment: What does return as "python objects" mean? It looks like it returns a json object to me

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be an effective way to convert a Boto 3 DynamoDB item to a Python dict.

https://github.com/Alonreznik/dynamodb-json

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat related answer, the docs advertise [the `query` method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning); their e.g.:

```py
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('username').eq('johndoe')
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```