# How can I pass a variable properly into this boto3 batch_get_item function?

Tags: python, boto3

A small example can be seen here on how to pass in hard coded values for batch_get_item

[Is there a Python API for submitting batch get requests to AWS DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872542/is-there-a-python-api-for-submitting-batch-get-requests-to-aws-dynamodb)

and the documentation is here

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item

but I can hardly believe this is how an experienced python user would pass in keys to the function. Is it possible to pass in a list of strings (ids) into the Keys array and how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to create the value that needs to be passed to `batch_get_item` as the `Keys` parameter.  Something like this would work:

```
# assume ids is a list of strings representing the ids you want to retrieve
# also assume that the primary key is called primary_key
keys = [{'primary_key': {'S': i}} for i in ids]
db_client.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems = {
        "my_table": {
            "Keys": keys
        }
    }
)
```

If `keys` had a value of `['foo', 'bar', 'fie', 'baz']` the value of `keys` in the code above would be:

```
[{'primary_key': {'S': 'foo'}},
 {'primary_key': {'S': 'bar'}},
 {'primary_key': {'S': 'fie'}},
 {'primary_key': {'S': 'baz'}}]
```